# What type of wall texture is this?

Tags: walls, texture

[image]

I'm trying to repair a wall and need to know what type of texture this is. Thank you.

Comment: It looks like it was put on with a sponge.

Comment: are there fibers embedded in the surface?

Answer (score 1):

It is not specific so it is a matter of trial and error. Various sponges but also mops are used. It also depends on pressure and movement of the tool. My builder called it "Stomp"  and says he always uses the same painter who has sponge that is decades old so he can make matching alterations later.

Comment: Practice a bit first. I've seen "learn as you go" jobs, and they are seldom pretty.